# How to reassign key 'cmd' in Mac. And in what file I should do it?

Tags: emacs

I want to reassign key 'cmd' to Ctrl. I have a application for Desktop and for console. I should do it for application for Desktop (GNU Emacs).

I create a file in ~/.emacs.d/init.el and write:

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'ctrl)
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe it file belong to console application, I don't know.

Comment: You should ask your question on [Emacs SE](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/) website.

Comment: Why would you want to handicap yourself by removing the ability to use the command key as a modifier?  You can always define additional keyboard shortcuts -- assigning them to control, or assigning them to command, or assigning them to meta, or a slew of other options that can be configured.

Comment: Because key 'cmd' is more comfortable for my hand than key 'Ctrl'. Key 'cmd' is more close.

Comment: You can have the best of all worlds, without handicapping yourself by disabling a modifier key -- just add a new keyboard shortcut to whichever modifier you wish to use:  `(defun hello-world-fn () (interactive) (message "Hello-world!")) (define-key global-map [s-f5] 'hello-world-fn) (define-key global-map [C-f5] 'hello-world-fn) (define-key global-map [M-f5] 'hello-world-fn)`  When Emacs is built for OSX using the option `--with-ns`, the control map is not altered and you can still use it.  You can disable specific command shortcuts if you find yourself accidentally hitting it too much.

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread entitled **Remap command key in mac only for emacs**:  http://superuser.com/a/297454/206164  Your question may be a duplicate of that other thread.

Comment: (setq mac-command-modifier 'C) - works for me! Thanks!